# ionic4 ion-toggle checked

Tags: typescript, ionic, toggle, ionicframework

html:

```
<ion-toggle id="t1"></ion-toggle>
```

ts:

```
let toggle = (<HTMLElement> document.getElementById('t1')).getAttribute('checked');
    if (toggle==true){
              console.log('this toggle is true')
             }
            else if (toggle==false){
              console.log('this one is false')
             }
```

err:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and
>   'true' have no overlap.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался. Что можно сделать, чтобы проверялось checked или нет и чтобы выводило в лог?

Comment: `getAttribute` возвращает `string`, а не `boolean`, если там строковое значение `true` или `false`, то можешь использовать `JSON.parse`, либо же просто сравнивать со строкой `if (toggle === 'true') { ... } else { .. }`

Comment: html:
<ion-toggle slot="start" mode="ios" checked="false"></ion-toggle>

ts:
window.onload = function () { 
      let toggle = (<HTMLElement> document.getElementById('t1')).getAttribute('checked');
    if (toggle === "true") console.log('this toggle is true');
            else if (toggle === "false") console.log('this one is false'); 
      }

Comment: console:
core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at window.onload (dashboard.page.ts:43)
    at wrapFn (zone.js:1332)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTa

Comment: sk (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
    at globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)

Comment: я не знаю зачем ты это вставил и что ты вообще за велосипед пытаешься сделать :)